# The program can’t start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program

Tags: dll, oracle-sqldeveloper

Long ago, I installed 32-bit Oracle SQL Developer 2.1 on a Windows XP (32-bit) machine. I have since moved to Windows 7 (64-bit) and copied the SQL Developer 2.1 from the old machine onto the new one.

When I try to run `sqldeveloper.exe`, I get the following message:

> The program can’t start because MSVCR71.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program.

I know that this is because of 32-bit software which was installed in Windows XP is incompatible with 64-bit machine. Is there any alternative to open 32-bit software on a 64-bit machine, or do I need to install the 64-bit version of Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: Just curious what this has to do with Java?

Comment: @Kon - Hi the only reason why i added 'Java' tag is as Oracle SQL Developer tool is build in Java.

Comment: @Kon- check it out http://java2go.blogspot.in/2007/09/sqldeveloper-trick.html

Comment: 32 bit application works on 64 bit machine, as long as you have 'C:\Program Files (x86)'. But it is not recommend to use 32 bit application of 64 bit machine, always go for 64 bit software installation.

Comment: Just curious, why stick to version 2.1? I'd have thought moving to a new machine was a good time to upgrade; version 4 was release recently.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

[How to fix the missing MSVCR711.dll problem](http://i.justrealized.com/2009/how-to-fix-missing-msvcr71dll-problem-in-windows/)

You can find `MSVCR71.dll` file in following location of your installed SQL Developer 2.1 directory:

```
sqldeveloper-2.1.0.63.10\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin\MSVCR71.dll
```

Comment: I followed the instruction in the link and it worked great!! I have win 8.1 +1

Comment: @nooblar - Sorry the link which i have posted earlier seems to be broken, you can try this link: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/msvcr71-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm

Comment: This helped me realize I had the wrong Java version in my environment.  It was 7 but should have been 6.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this page](http://oraclenz.org/?p=3355):

- Run regedit (remember to run it as the administrator)
- Expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- Expand SOFTWARE
- Expand Microsoft
- Expand Windows
- Expand CurrentVersion
- Expand App Paths
- At App Paths, add a new KEY called sqldeveloper.exe
- Expand sqldeveloper.exe
- Modify the (DEFAULT) value to the full pathway to the sqldeveloper executable (See example below step 11)
- Create a new STRING VALUE called PATH and set it value to the sqldeveloper pathway + \jdk\jre\bin

Answer (score 1):

I found this error occurred when I was using the wrong version of Java.  When I changed my environment from Java 7 down to Java 6 the error no longer appeared.

(The *MSVCR71.DLL* file is in the JDK 6 `bin` directory, where JDK 7 has *MSVCR100.DLL*.)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with jcadcell comments, but had to use JDK 1.8 because my eclipse need that. So I just copied the MSVCR71.DLL from jdk1.6 and pasted into jdk1.8 in both the folder jdk1.8.0_121\bin and jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin

and it Worked  .... Wow... Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

MY SOLUTION!!!!!!!
I fixed this problem when I was trying to install business objects.
When the installer failed to register .dll's I inputted the MSVCR71.dll into both system32 and sysWOW64 then clicked retry. Installation finished.
I did try adding this in before and after install but, install still failed.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a solution if the install still failed?